# Does MS Lync server 2010 come with a built-in vxml browser?

Tags: vxml, lync-server-2010

If so, is there any online document describing how to install/configure it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is available as an out of the box server you can configure and use, but I believe the APIs are there for someone to build a Vxml browser.

Lync VoiceXML Sample (QuickStart) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg448288.aspx

VoiceXML Support in UCMA 3.0 Core - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg448321.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Lync does support a VXML browser through UCMA 3.0.  If you are interested in a free IVR that uses UCMAs VXML browser without the use of Lync check out www.FoneRage.com